# How to capture packets at the Ethernet layer on a SOCKS5 proxy server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet, wireshark, sniffing

When I capture packets with tcpdump on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM running a SOCKS proxy server on port 1080, they are often larger than 1500 bytes. My network device has an MTU of 1500, so as far as I understand it, this means that they are being reassembled. Since I want to analyze the timing and size of the packets on the wire, I would like to capture them before they are reassembled, or not have them reassembled at all. Is there any way to do this, or do I need to use a completely different setup?

When I use NetfilterQueue along with iptables, the maximum packet sizes surprisingly become 1500. I don't really understand this effect. Are the packets being disassembled or not reassembled at all?

I tried changing various options for tcpdump. However, it had no effect.

Comment: you may want to consider wireshark instead. I believe TCPDump will only go down to the packet level, so to get ethernet frames, you likely need a different tool.

Comment: as for your segment length issue, I'd guess that the segment was fragmented at the IP layer. TCP doesn't care about MTU, but IP does, so the segment may have been broken up over multiple packets. IP fragmentation is transparent to the TCP layer, so a capture at the TCP layer won't be able to tell a segment that was contained in multiple packets from a segment that was delivered in one.

Comment: @FrankThomas Ethernet: `tcpdump -e` (now ok, wireshark has details tcpdump doesn't have).